# ()operator and <<operator lead to memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, overloading

The following code leads to a memory leak (Tested with xcode 7.0.1 and mac os 10.11). The leak is located in this line: `std::cout << m(0,0) << std::endl;`  Could someone explain why? When I remove this line, the leak disappears. I guess it has something to do with the overloading of the ()operator, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Matrix.h:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix {

public:
    Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns, T initValue)
    : size_(rows*columns), columns_(columns), rows_(rows) {
        data_ = new T[size_];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
            data_[i] = initValue;
        }
    }

    Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns)
    : columns_(columns), rows_(rows) {
        data_ = new T[size_];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
            data_[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        delete [] data_;
    }

    T& operator()(const unsigned int &row, const unsigned int &column) {
        assert(row < rows_ && column < columns_);
        return data_[row * columns_ + column];
    }

    T operator()(const unsigned int &row, const unsigned int &column) const {
        assert(row < rows_ && column < columns_);
        return data_[row * columns_ + column];
    }

private:
    T *data_;
    unsigned int size_, columns_, rows_;

};
```

Main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Matrix<double> m( 2,2, 1.0 );
    std::cout << m(0,0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Although not the cause of a memory leak in this case, your class is vulnerable to memory leaks because it doesn't provide an appropriate copy constructor and assignment operator. The easiest way to fix that is to use `std::vector` which manages its own memory. Then you don't need to provide those things, or even your own destructor any more.

Comment: @Neil Kirk: Yes, I'm aware about that. I just didn't want to add my full source. The reason for not using a vector is, that it's an exercise for a lecture and we're not supposed to use stl.

Comment: You do not initialize `size_` in your second constructor. Besides that, the code looks fine., so fix that and try again.

Comment: 37 seconds faster than me. I saw the same thing, `size_` is unitialized

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: Thanks, didn't see that!

Comment: @Amadeus Being the Fastest Gun in the West is the key to success on this site. :D